# Core Data migration failure between NSPersistenceFrameworkVersions 251 and 358

Tags: core-data, osx-lion, core-data-migration

I have what appears to be a bug with Core Data in OS X 10.7.1.

My data store (NSSQLiteStoreType) is not being automatically migrated correctly.

As a side note the exact same Core Data models are used by an iOS version of the app.

-> Here is what appears to be happening.

Up until the latest release everything has been working fine --

I have 14 revisions of the model -- model 13 has been shipping for quite some time without incident.

Recently I updated my app and added a new model so I am at 14 (this is the version now used in the shipping apps).

The iOS version works just fine when migrating from model 13 to 14 -- so no need to worry about that.

So rather then talking about OS X versions lets use NSPersistenceFrameworkVersions

NSPersistenceFrameworkVersions 251 being 10.6.8 and NSPersistenceFrameworkVersions 358 being 10.7.1

If we use like versions -- meaning model 13 version 251 and migrate to model 14 version 251 it works fine.

same is true if we use model 13 version 358 and migrate to model 14 version 358 it also works fine

Here is where it gets interesting

if we migrate model 13 version 358 to model 14 version 251 it still works fine

However migrating from model 13 version 251 to model 14 version 358 does **not** work

CoreData: error: (1) I/O error for database at blah. SQLite error code:1, 'no such column: FOK_REFLEXIVE'

Again this only happens when going from 10.6.8 (NSPersistenceFrameworkVersions 251) to 10.7.1 (NSPersistenceFrameworkVersions 358) all other permutations work just fine.

Here are the options used for migration that get passed to addPersistentStoreWithType.

```
// Allow inferred migration from the original version of the application.
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];
```

One final thing, it appears if we only add attributes to model 14 the conversion will **not** break. It is only with the addition of an entity that will cause it to break.

Anybody else seeing this sort of problem. -thanks in advance.

Comment: I have been experiencing a similar problem using Core Data on iOS 5 beta. I have been able to resolve this problem by removing the item and recreating it, but haven't been able to save all of the data.

Comment: @Jason - did you find a solution - losing the data isn't really an option for me! :)

Comment: I actually hacked core data so that if the table doesn't have the column, I manually added it via direct SQLite manipulation. It isn't pretty but it works perfectly.

Comment: The problem appears to be with inferred mapping. Providing a mapping model (xcmappingmodel) makes the problem go away.

Comment: @Jason: Do you have details on how you did this? I'm trying to catch the exception and re-exec the SQL, but that fails because NSSQLiteConnection seems to close the connection before the exception is thrown.

Comment: I didn't catch the exception. I checked to see if the missing column is there or not. If the column is not there, then I create it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug appears to have been fixed in iOS 5.1 and OSX 10.7.3

Comment: please expand with some examples, demonstration, documentation links.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, 
use the unix sqlite3 tool with the path to the database file as a parameter. 
You can get your app's db file by pulling it from the organizer's device pane under Applications for a device... You'll get a package.

type ".headers on" for table headers

Find tables (.tables command) for entities with references between objects

Where Z_1REFERENCEDSETOFOBJECTS is the name of your table.

```
select * from Z_1REFERENCEDSETOFOBJECTS limit 2
```

to find the names of the table's headers; then run the following for the tables that have the REFLEXIVE column:

```
ALTER TABLE Z_1REFERENCEDSETOFOBJECTS ADD FOK_REFLEXIVE integer
```

Push it back down.