# Core Data Lightweight Migration and Reflexive Relationships under iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

Since the iOS 5 Betas I have been testing my app's code and the lightweight migration bit for my Core Data model has been failing. I get the "no such column: FOK_REFLEXIVE" error, but strangely I get it on the first run on devices and the simulator when no older version is present. I have changed nothing since the iOS 4.x code that worked beautifully.

The full error gives no extra information about the error and after pounding my head on the table for a bit I may have narrowed down the error to a reflexive relationship in my data model. Name has a many-to-many relationship with Name via a relationship called, names. (The idea is that Rob is related to Bob and Robert, etc). Can this all of a sudden be taboo in iOS 5?

Also, does Core Data run through every version of the data model and migrate for each no matter what version of the data model the app should be using? It's strange to get a migration error on an app being run for the very first time I would think.

Here's the only related code although it's Marcus Zarra's code which I believe everyone on Earth is using.

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (persistentStoreCoordinator_ != nil) {
        return persistentStoreCoordinator_;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Saline.sqlite"]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    persistentStoreCoordinator_ = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![persistentStoreCoordinator_ addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil] error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Schema changes...");
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return persistentStoreCoordinator_;
}
```

UPDATE: Full error follows

```
2011-10-20 08:14:17.700 Saline[28315:207] CoreData: error: (1) I/O error for database at /Users/rob5408/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/865AD162-49BC-4809-A63A-23E6D5A5E5C4/Documents/.Saline.sqlite.migrationdestination_41b5a6b5c6e848c462a8480cd24caef3.  SQLite error code:1, 'no such column: FOK_REFLEXIVE'
2011-10-20 08:14:17.731 Saline[28315:207] Schema changes...
2011-10-20 08:14:17.732 Saline[28315:207] Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134110 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134110.)" UserInfo=0x6f7b2d0 {destinationURL=file://localhost/Users/rob5408/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.0/Applications/865AD162-49BC-4809-A63A-23E6D5A5E5C4/Documents/.Saline.sqlite.migrationdestination_41b5a6b5c6e848c462a8480cd24caef3, reason=Cannot migrate store in-place: I/O error for database at /Users/rob5408/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/865AD162-49BC-4809-A63A-23E6D5A5E5C4/Documents/.Saline.sqlite.migrationdestination_41b5a6b5c6e848c462a8480cd24caef3.  SQLite error code:1, 'no such column: FOK_REFLEXIVE', NSUnderlyingError=0x6f7cda0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134110.)", sourceURL=file://localhost/Users/rob5408/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.0/Applications/865AD162-49BC-4809-A63A-23E6D5A5E5C4/Documents/Saline.sqlite}, {
NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134110 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 134110.)\" UserInfo=0x6f75780 {NSSQLiteErrorDomain=1, NSFilePath=/Users/rob5408/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/865AD162-49BC-4809-A63A-23E6D5A5E5C4/Documents/.Saline.sqlite.migrationdestination_41b5a6b5c6e848c462a8480cd24caef3, reason=I/O error for database at /Users/rob5408/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/865AD162-49BC-4809-A63A-23E6D5A5E5C4/Documents/.Saline.sqlite.migrationdestination_41b5a6b5c6e848c462a8480cd24caef3.  SQLite error code:1, 'no such column: FOK_REFLEXIVE', NSUnderlyingException=I/O error for database at /Users/rob5408/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/865AD162-49BC-4809-A63A-23E6D5A5E5C4/Documents/.Saline.sqlite.migrationdestination_41b5a6b5c6e848c462a8480cd24caef3.  SQLite error code:1, 'no such column: FOK_REFLEXIVE'}";
destinationURL = "file://localhost/Users/rob5408/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.0/Applications/865AD162-49BC-4809-A63A-23E6D5A5E5C4/Documents/.Saline.sqlite.migrationdestination_41b5a6b5c6e848c462a8480cd24caef3";
reason = "Cannot migrate store in-place: I/O error for database at /Users/rob5408/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/865AD162-49BC-4809-A63A-23E6D5A5E5C4/Documents/.Saline.sqlite.migrationdestination_41b5a6b5c6e848c462a8480cd24caef3.  SQLite error code:1, 'no such column: FOK_REFLEXIVE'";
sourceURL = "file://localhost/Users/rob5408/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.0/Applications/865AD162-49BC-4809-A63A-23E6D5A5E5C4/Documents/Saline.sqlite";
}
```

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536223/

Comment: @tc. Actually my problem was that upon app loading I was swooping in with another store created off of an old model and replacing the correct store. I'd be surprised if anyone was as stupid as me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data migration *only* migrations from the existing store to the current model.  It will not go through every model type.  So you need to make sure you can migration from whatever the store is in to what the current model is.

Did you actually name an attribute `FOK_REFLEXIVE`?  Is this perhaps a sqlite store being created by something other than Core Data?

What is the full error?

A migration will only occur when there is a store to migrate.  I would test to see if there is a file on disk when you get an error as that would be the only thing that would kick off a migration.

### UPDATE

This *really* points to an existing file.  Since you are running in the simulator what happens if you just look using the console?

```
ls -la /Users/rob5408/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/865AD162-49BC-4809-A63A-23E6D5A5E5C4/Documents
```

What do you see? Or try:

```
find /Users/rob5408/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator | grep sqlite
```

Another option is to turn on SQL debug and lets see what the output is.  You can do this by adding the argument `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 3` to your executable and watching the console output.  I would be interested in seeing the results.

Comment: Hi Marcus, honored! I posted the full error above. I'm positive about no earlier versions of files laying around. It was even happening on a newly Apple Store wiped phone. Here's an odd thing though, when re-re-re-testing the code just now I at first failed to also rename my data store file (from .salbin back to .sqlite) and it worked. I know this would lend more credence to the "existing file" theory, but I'm positive it's not that. Could it be iOS' handling of SQLite stores named .sqlite? When reading about switching store types I also read that you should use a custom file extension.

Comment: Ugh, I feel ill. It was what you said. A looong time ago I included a seed db that gets moved over on first run (from the app bundle to Documents). I totally forgot about it even being there. I fell victim to the "it's no my code it must be an SDK bug" fallacy. Just took an expert to get me to read the error message one more time. Many thanks. Oy.

Answer (score 1):

You always come up with a solution two seconds after posting...

I tried just changing the store type to binary thinking other store types probably don't have the concept of "columns" and may not be vulnerable to a column issue. So that worked, but I like using sqlite better because it's easier to debug (poor reasoning, i'm aware).

Therefore I'm still open to a solution to get reflexive relationships working under sqlite.

Comment: First, be aware that binary and sqlite perform differently.  A binary store will load **fully** into memory whereas sqlite will only load what you need.  You are going to have a different memory signature using Binary.